# Javascript problems with submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am not very familiar with javascript and I need a help here. I want to submit a form using JavaScript. Here is a code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
</script>

<form name="myform" action="index.php?id=search">
    <div class="searchleft"><?php  echo $search['search']; ?>:</div>
    <div class="searchbox"><input type="text" name="query" id="searchbox"></div>
    <div class="searchbtn"><input name="search" onClick="submitform()" type="button"></div>
</form>
```

I want link after pressing a button to look like: `http://127.0.0.1/index.php?id=search&query=blabla`, but unfortunately it looks: `http://127.0.0.1/index.php?query=blabla`
What do I have to change to make it look as I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `hidden` field:

```
<form name="myform" action="index.php?id=search">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="search" />
    <div class="searchleft"><?php  echo $search['search']; ?>:</div>
    <div class="searchbox"><input type="text" name="query" id="searchbox"></div>
    <div class="searchbtn"><input name="search" onClick="submitform()" type="button"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only the one input on the form when it's submitted. I'm not familiar with php, but if you put search in a hidden field, it will come through on the post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must define your method, either "GET" or "POST", in this case, if you don't want url variables you should use POST.